# Frog game on tree graphs is in NP but not in P (NP-complete)?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, trees, discrete-dynamical-systems

**Problem**

We can restrict ourselves to tree graphs. What is the complexity of the following problem?

Let $G$ be simple connected graph with vertices in $V$, edges in $E$, and a vertex weighted function $f$ (counting frogs on vertices). Given $G$ and a vertex $v\in V$, is the frog game solvable in $v$?

---

**Frog game rules**

To play the frog game, start by placing one frog on each vertex: $f_0(u)=1,u\in V$.

Given $G$ and $f_k=f$ after $k$ moves have been made, a new move consists of:

1. Selecting two nonempty (contain at least one frog, i.e. $f(v_1),f(v_2)\gt 0$) vertices $v_1, v_2\in V$ that are connected by a path of $f(v_1)$ distinct edges.
2. Moving all frogs from $v_1$ to $v_2$: $f_{k+1}(v_1)=0$ and $f_{k+1}(v_2)=f_k(v_2)+f_k(v_1)$.

That is, all frogs on a vertex $v$ must jump over exactly $f(v)$ distinct edges and onto a nonempty vertex. (Imagine the vertex being a lily pad and sinking after frogs jump off of it.).

We say that the frog game is solvable in some vertex $v\in V$ if there exists a sequence of moves such that all frogs end up in the vertex $v$: Meaning $f_0, f_1, \dots, f_{n-1}, n=|V|$ where $f_{n-1}(u)=|V|$ for $u=v$ and $f_{n-1}(u)=0$ for $u\ne v$.

*[Here is a short presentation with examples](https://mathpickle.com/project/lazy-toad-puzzles-counting-symmetry/).*

I suspect this problem is in NP but not in P (NP-complete?), can we prove this?

---

**Algorithmic approach**

We can solve this problem recursively.

For example, given a path graph "$v_1 - v_2 - v_3 - v_4 - v_5$" and the goal $v_2$;

We compute the multiset of path distances from the goal $v_2$ to other vertices: $D=\{1,1,2,3\}$.

We consider all partitions of $|V|-1=4$ that can be made with elements of $D$:

$$
\begin{array}{}
\text{A.} & 4 & = & 3 + 1\\
\text{B.} & 4 & = & 2 + 1 + 1\\
\end{array}
$$

Now we check each partition by assigning the respective vertices as new sub-goals (in all possible ways) and applying this procedure recursively. (Set $f(w)=0$ for unusable vertices $w$ within the sub-goal.)

$\text{A.}$ For example, when looking at the first partition, we have two possible selections of sub-goals. We can either consider $v_1$ or $v_3$, as both could be "$1$" in "$4=3+1$".

- If we take $v_3$, then the other sub-goal is graph "$v_1 - 0 - 0 - v_4 - v_5$" in $v_5$, but $2$ cannot be partitioned using elements of $D=\{4,1\}$, therefore this selection of sub-goals is impossible.
- If we take $v_1$, then the other sub-goal is graph "$0 - 0 - v_3 - v_4 - v_5$" in $v_5$, with $D=\{1,2\}$ and one possible partition "$2=2$". Going one step deeper, we get a trivial sub-sub-goal of "$v_3 - v_4$" in $v_3$ with trivial $D=\{1\}$ and partition "$1=1$". Therefore, this partition and selection of sub-goals gives a solution of the problem in $v_2$. Therefore, the graph is solvable in $v_2$.

$\text{B.}$ For example, when looking at the second partition, the jumps at distance $1$ are trivial and only possible selection for sub-goals, and the other sub-goal is to have $2$ frogs at vertex $v_4$ using the remaining usable vertices $v_4-v_5$; that is, it is again a trivial sub-goal with $D=\{1\}$ and partition "$1=1$". Therefore, the graph is solvable in $v_2$.

In general, this procedure is exponential at worst. When the vertex is not solvable, we will need to check all partitions and all selections of sub-goals.

Can we do better? (Is it possible that this problem is in P?)

---

Note that it is not hard to prove that path graphs $P_k$ specifically, i.e. "$v_1-v_2-\dots-v_k$", are solvable in every vertex for every $k\in\mathbb N$. That is, certain classes of graphs can be solved in terms of theorems, by explicitly constructing sequences of jumps that solve vertices or showing certain vertices are never solvable.

But I doubt that can be done for all tree graphs.

---

*Note that I posted a similar question a long time ago on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/149805/83577), asking about a better approach than the exponential partition analysis (here I ask about complexity class), but there I got nothing new after two bounties. (Not sure if this counts as a cross-post, but I'll link it here just in case).*

Comment: I am slightly confused and maybe misunderstood the problem, but isn’t the frog game winnable for any vertex of any tree (and a fortiori any connected graph by passing to a spanning tree): just put a root at this vertex and start moving frogs from the bottom level up. All this is doable in polynomial (maybe even linear) time.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov You misunderstood the rules. For example, a [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) is not solvable in leaf vertices if it has $3$ or more leaves. The $f$ frogs must jump exactly over $f$ edges, and can't jump to empty vertices (with no frogs).

Comment: What is $\phi$? I thought that it was a vertex weighting function and that $f(v_1)$ was a typo for $\phi(v_1)$ until I looked at the linked examples and realised that $f(v_1)$ is a typo for $f_k(v_1)$.

Comment: Also, the question itself is trivial: the sequence of $f_k$ is a certificate which can be verified in polynomial time. Perhaps the question is intended to be whether the problem is in P?

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is the incidence function, mapping every edge to an unordered pair of vertices (that is, an edge is associated with two distinct vertices). Is that not the standard way to define graphs? Using sets of edges and vertices, and a function that relates them.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah yes sorry, I meant to ask that (In NP and not in P).

Comment: You might want 'NP complete' — there are after all _no_ problems known to be in NP and not in P...

Comment: The standard I'm used to from the literature is $G = (V, E)$ where $E$ is a set of unordered or ordered pairs according to whether the graph is undirected or directed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've checked again, it seems your definition is more common when talking about simple graphs, and mine when talking about multigraphs, but I've seen it used vice versa. Maybe it is best to just specify $V,E$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Well it is an open problem, but I agree, thanks for the comment.